# Remove host previously added with --add-host from running docker container

Tags: docker

I previously started a container by using `docker run --add-host myserver:123.45.67.89 --name my-container <etc>`

Now I want to update *THAT* container, so that I remove "myserver" from the containers hosts file.

How do I do that?

I basically need `docker service update --host-rm` for a container and not a service.... Since I haven't put my stuff in a service.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Stop the docker host service. 
Then go to the data folder of the designated container.

A location like this:
`/<docker-root>/containers/<container-id>`

Then edit config.v2.json file there and remove the desired extraHosts in the json.
Also edit hosts file and remove the lines from it.
Save and restart the docker host service.

Done!